# Is every countable model of ZFC a subset of some parameter free definable pointwise-definable model of ZFC?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, model-theory, definability

Is it consistent with $\sf ZFC + \text{ countable models of } ZFC \text {  exist}$,  that every countable model of $\sf ZFC$ is a subset of some parameter free definable pointwise-definable model of $\sf ZFC$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The answer is in the positive. Since by the completeness theorem the existence of a countable model of ZFC is equivalent to Con(ZFC), the argument below works with the assumption that ZFC + Con(ZFC) is consistent.

Wojowu's answer already points out that the proof of the following fact (S) can be found in the paper [Pointwise Definable Models of Set Theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/1105.4597) (JSL 2013) by Hamkins, Linetsky, and Reitz.

**(S)**   Every countable model of ZFC has a (class) generic extension to model of ZFC that is pointwise definable.

[*Historical note:* (S) was asserted with a proof outline in my paper [Models of set theory with definable ordinals](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220592523_Models_of_set_theory_with_definable_ordinals), which includes a detailed proof of the weaker statement: *every countable model of ZFC has a generic extension in which all the ordinals are parameter-free definable*. The paper of Hamkins-Linetsky-Reitz presents a detailed proof of not only (S), but also of a corresponding result for countable models of GBC].

Note that (S) is a theorem of ZFC (indeed, it is provable in much weaker systems , but that is a different story). It is easy to see that if the theory ZFC + Con(ZFC) is consistent, then so is $T$ = ZFC + Con(ZFC) + V = L. The fact that $T$ includes the statement V = L implies that $T$ has a global well-ordering of its ambient universe and therefore $T$ has definable Skolem functions. This immediately implies that $T$ has a pointwise definable model $M$. Since (S) is a theorem of ZFC, it holds in $M$, and moreover EVERYTHING in $M$ is parameter-free definable. Thus $M$ is a model in which every countable $N$ model of ZFC has a (class) generic extension $N[G]$ such that (1) $N[G]$ is pointwise definable, and (2) $N[G]$ is parameter-free definable in $M$.

Answer (score 5):

This is not only consistent, it is provably true. From Hamkins-Linetsky-Reitz's [Pointwise Definable Models of Set Theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/1105.4597):

> Theorem 11. Every countable model of ZFC has a pointwise definable class forcing extension.

Comment: What is the proof that these forcing extensions are parameter free definable? Or that at least one of them should be?

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar I slightly misunderstood your question. The property you ask for is not itself expressible in the language of ZFC, but it will hold in any pointwise definable model of ZFC.

Comment: I don't think so, because you have continuum many of them

Comment: To complete your proof you need to add the proof that at least one of those forcing extensions is parameter free definable, like proving that it is an element of some point-wise definable model of ZFC, or something similar to that.

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar Forcing extensions need not be pointwise definable, the point of specifying them is that "subset" can be strengthened to "submodel with the same class of ordinals" in your question.  In other words, given any countable model M of ZFC, there is a pointwise definable model N of ZFC such that (1) M is a submodel of N, and (2) N has no more ordinals than M.

Comment: @AliEnayat, I didn't get your argument. What I asked was about if every countable model M of ZFC can be a subset of some pointwise-definable model N of ZFC and such that N itself is a parameter free definable set. That was my question. So, is it the case?

Comment: To clarify (and @AliEnayat) I think the point is that we're looking at how $N$ itself sits inside $V$. That is, if $M$ is a countable (transitive?) model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$, must there exist some $N$ such that $M\in N$, $N$ is a p.d. model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$, and $N$ is itself a definable element of the whole set-theoretic universe $V$. Zuhair, is this accurate?

Comment: @NoahSchweber, if $M$ is a countable model of ZFC must there exists some set $N$ such that $M \subset N$ and $N$ is pointwise-definable model of ZFC, and $N$ itself is a parameter free definable element of $V$.

Comment: Looking back at the question, and taking it as face value, the answer is trivially yes, since there are models of ZFC in which Con(ZFC) fails, and therefore sentences of the form "every model of ZFC has such-and-such property" are automatically true.

Comment: @AliEnayat, True, but that is not really the question. The question pre-suppose the existence of countable models of ZFC. I'll add this to the question. Thanks.